# Python String to Escaped Hex

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, hex

I have some python code below I managed to cobble together to achieve what I needed, but being quite new to python I believe there should be a much more elegant solution than the one I have here.

Essentially I need to take an arbitrary string (`MAGICSTRING`) and convert each of it's characters into their hex value, then pad a 0x00 to the start and end of the resultant hex string, and finally put the hex value of the length of the entire padded string on the end. I then need these escaped so it can be passed to a socket connection later on.

In the example, `MAGICSTRING` is 1234, and the expected result of 'value' is `'\x00\x31\x32\x33\x34\x00\x06'`

See below example.

```
MAGICSTRING = '1234'
i=0
hexpass = ''
while i < len(MAGICSTRING):
    hexpass = hexpass + hex(ord(MAGICSTRING[i]))[2:]
    i += 1
strlen = len(MAGICSTRING) + 2
sendstr = '00'+ hexpass + '00' + '0' + hex(strlen)[2:]
value = sendstr.decode('hex')
```

Appreciate any improvements that can be made to the above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The string `'1234'` is **already** equivalent to `'\x31\x32\x33\x34'`:

```
>>> '\x31\x32\x33\x34'
'1234'
>>> '\x31\x32\x33\x34' == '1234'
True
```

thus encoding that to hex then decoding it again is.. busy work:

```
>>> '1234'.encode('hex').decode('hex')
'1234'
```

`\xhh` is just a *notation* to help you create the values; when echoing a byte string Python will always display printable ASCII characters directly rather than use the `\xhh` notation.

Hex notation here is just a way to express the values of each byte, which is really an integer between 0 and 255. Each byte in a Python string is then a byte with such a constrained value, and encoding to the `'hex'` codec produces a string with hex digits for those bytes, and bytes again from the hex digits.

As such, all you have to do is add the `\x00` null bytes and the length:

```
MAGICSTRING = '1234'
value = '\x00{}\x00{}'.format(MAGICSTRING, chr(len(MAGICSTRING) + 2))
```

Here the `\xhh` notation is used to produce the null bytes, and the [`chr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) produces the length 'byte'.

Demo:

```
>>> MAGICSTRING = '1234'
>>> '\x00{}\x00{}'.format(MAGICSTRING, chr(len(MAGICSTRING) + 2))
'\x001234\x00\x06'
>>> '\x00{}\x00{}'.format(MAGICSTRING, chr(len(MAGICSTRING) + 2)) == '\x00\x31\x32\x33\x34\x00\x06'
True
```

Comment: One line of code. Simple, elegant solution.
Working just as expected. Thank you!

Comment: This asnwer doesn't work for me "LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs"

Comment: @GM: you are using Python 3, which doesn't support binary-to-binary codecs in `bytes.decode()` and `str.encode()`. This question is tagged with `python-2.7` where the bytestring type `str` has an `str.encode()` method that would let you use any code to encode from bytes to bytes. You could use the `codecs` module directly, but you'd instead want to use the [`binascii` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html), or encode strings to bytes (using whatever codec you feel works best for the text) and then `bytes.fromhex()` and `bytesvalue.hex()`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and sorry for the mistake I did not see the tag.