# How to convert between b'\\xe5' and b'\xe5' with python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

How to convert  between  b'\\xe5' and b'\xe5' with python3?
1.convert b'\\xe5' into b'\xe5'?
2.convert b'\xe5' into b'\\xe5'?

Comment: Did you try with some regular exp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python String to Escaped Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275085/python-string-to-escaped-hex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode your bytes using the [unicode_escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) encoding, then convert the resulting string back to bytes by encoding it with `latin1`, which is a one to one encoding between bytes and characters:

```
b'abc\\xe5\\xe6'.decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1')
# b'abc\xe5\xe6'
```

And in the opposite direction:

```
b'abc\xe5\xe6'.decode('latin-1').encode('unicode_escape')
# b'abc\\xe5\\xe6'
```