# Is there any function to get utf-8 encoding output text in python?

Tags: python, utf-8

How to get the output of encoded text in utf-8 ?
such as "hi" it's output of encoding "\x68\x69" 
How to print "\x68\x69" in python ?
such as this site https://mothereff.in/utf-8#

UTF-8-decoded:

hi there

UTF-8-encoded:

\x68\x69\x20\x74\x68\x65\x72\x65

Comment: Hmm.... So the use of the term "UTF-8 encoding" here is extremely dubious. What you're really asking for is escaped hex -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275085 . mothereff.in has really done a disservice by not clarifying on the page, these escape sequences can be used in JavaScript to be encoded into a JavaScript string which is UTF-8.

Comment: Are you able to provide what you have done so far and what it does not do correctly? Please refer to
[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Zv_ODD JavaScript strings are _not_ UTF-8. The tool takes a Unicode string and prints its UTF-8-encoded byte sequence, in the format `\x41\x42\x43`.

Comment: My mistake, I had thought I had read the JS spec had strings as UTF-8 internally. That is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get UTF-8 bytes of a string:

```py
data = 'hi'.encode('utf-8')
```

Printing data bytes yield:

```
>>> print(data)
b'hi'
```

To print hexadecimal value of each byte:

```py
>>> [*map(hex, data)]
['0x68', '0x69']
```

Or, equivalently:

```py
>>> [f'\\x{x:02x}' for x in data]
['\\x68', '\\x69']
```

To get result in your format, join each hexadecimal value:

```py
>>> print(''.join(f'\\x{x:02x}' for x in data))
\x68\x69
```

Comment: As an aside, `[*map(hex, data)]` is really not idiomatic. Just use `list(map(hex, data))`, the  other notation is for things like `[foo, bar, *some_iterable, baz]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `[*map(f, data)]` is convenient in exploratory coding, giving easier transition to `[x for x in data]` and back. So -1 to whoever decided it's not idiomatic.